# Redirect specific options of a select box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select box where the users needs to select something in a form. For the first options, the  act as normal, but the last two options needs to redirect the users on another page if he selects them.

So far i have this

```
<script>
function redirect(what) {
var index = what.selectedIndex;
var value = what.options[index].value;

if (value != 7) return;
window.location.href='http://www.example.com';
}
</script>
```

But now i need to add another redirection.

If the users selects option 7, then redirect to example.com
If users selects option 8, then redirect to google.com

how can i do that ?

Comment: To get the value you can use `what.value` instead of `what.options[what.selectedIndex].value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value != 7 && value != 8) return;
    if (value == 7){
        window.location.href='http://www.example.com';
    }else if (value == 8){
        window.location.href='http://www.example.com/2';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var mapURLs = {
    7: 'http://www.example.com',
    8: 'http://www.example.com/foobar'
};
function redirect(what) {
    var value = what.value;
    if (!mapURLs.hasOwnProperty(value)) return;
    window.location.href = mapURLs[value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4caMc/1/)):

**HTML:**

```
<select id = 'sel'>
    <option value='http://google.com'>Google</option>
    <option value='http://yahoo.com'>Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('sel').onchange = function() {
    window.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
}
```